# Should I scribe a floor reducer over an uneven floor?

Tags: flooring

I have a tile to hardwood transition and I have my reducer cut and ready to go.
The problem is the floor is not quite level. Should I just glue it down and put some heavy items on it while the glue cures or should I scribe it?

If I should scribe it, what is the best way to go about it? How do I transfer what where to scribe and do I use a belt sander for those areas?

Alternatively, I could just put more adhesive on the parts that are lower... but that feels hacky.

[image]

Comment: If you can you use any part of the door jamb to hold the edges down you could undercut some the door jamb and shove the reducer in it for it to bend to the floor. Otherwise, glue and weights is what I'd do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's flexible enough to bend without too much pressure, just glue it, close the door and wedge a few shims in to keep it down.

If it's really resistant to bending, you could cut a few invisible kerfs on the underside.